# .Net Core Refresh Token Not Working after Publish

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, refresh-token

I have an web application written in .Net Core both Backend + Frontend

I have login page with Email + Password + Remember Me ( Checkbox )

I want if user click on remember me stay signed in forever until he/she clear cookies.

When user logging in I save ACCESS_TOKEN + REFRESH_TOKEN in Principals Here is example of Login Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var requestDto = _mapper.Map<LoginRequestDto>(loginViewModel);

            try
            {
                var response = await _authenticationClient.LoginAsync(requestDto);

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.AccessToken, response.AccessToken),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.RefreshToken, response.RefreshToken),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.FullName, response.Fullname),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.UserName, response.Username),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.UserId, response.UserId),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.Email, response.Email),
                    new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.TokenExpireTime, response.TokenExpire.ToString())
                }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                var principals = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

                if (loginViewModel.IsPersistent)
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principals, new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                        IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principals, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false, AllowRefresh = true });
                }

                return new JsonResult(new
                {
                    success = true,
                    result = "/home"
                });
            }
            catch (ApiException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorResponse != null)
                {
                    return new JsonResult(new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        result = ex.ErrorResponse.Errors.Select(x => x.Message)
                    });
                }
                if (ex.Response != null)
                {
                    return new JsonResult(new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        result = ex.Response
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Token Expire Time is 5 Minutes, I want if user clicked remember me after this 5 minutes I need to refresh token to make sure access token is valid

Here is example of Refresh Token :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Authentication/Index";
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
                    {
                        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)x.Principal.Identity;

                        var tokenExpire = identity.FindFirst(CustomUserClaimTypes.TokenExpireTime);

                        if (DateTime.Parse(tokenExpire.Value) < DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            var accessTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst(CustomUserClaimTypes.AccessToken);
                            var refreshTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst(CustomUserClaimTypes.RefreshToken);


                            using (var client = new HttpClient())
                            {
                                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.api.com/api/v1/");

                                var requestData = new RefreshTokenRequestApiDto
                                {
                                    AccessToken = accessTokenClaim.Value,
                                    RefreshToken = refreshTokenClaim.Value
                                };
                                var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
                                var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                                var result = await client.PostAsync("auth/refresh-token", stringContent);

                                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    var deserializedData = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                    var mapped = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseApiResponse<BaseAuthenticationResponseDto>>(deserializedData);

                                    if (mapped != null)
                                    {
                                        identity.RemoveClaim(accessTokenClaim);
                                        identity.RemoveClaim(refreshTokenClaim);
                                        identity.RemoveClaim(tokenExpire);

                                        identity.AddClaims(new[]
                                        {
                                            new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.AccessToken, mapped.Result.AccessToken),
                                            new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.RefreshToken, mapped.Result.RefreshToken),
                                            new Claim(CustomUserClaimTypes.TokenExpireTime, mapped.Result.TokenExpire.ToString())
                                        });

                                        x.ShouldRenew = true;
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                };
            });
```

The problem is when I try on localhost everything working good, User is persist, even I turn off my PC, But when I publish this to my PLESK panel, and Try it from there, after 5 minutes user signed out and on cookie the AspNet.Cookies is exist but user seems unauthorized, I need to login again after 5 minutes continuously.

Anything wrong on my code ?

Or I need to do something on my Plesk Panel ?

SORRY ABOUT MY ENGLISH :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cookie before proceeding?

Comment: Yes, I even tried from incognito tab.